# Alternative to ngx-plyr & plyr

Tags: angular16

ngx-plyr and plyr are not compiled with angular 16 any more. So far, there has been no update to the package since it has been no longer maintained.  Is there any other packages to use (mainly for youtube and audio).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

They are compiled in my project and work without errors(Angular 16, Node 16.15.0), BUT ngx-plyr cause peer dependency conflicts on `npm install`, you can run

`npm install --legacy-peer-deps`
first to avoid errors, then manually install latest version of package

`npm install ngx-plyr@4.0.1 --legacy-peer-deps`

Library that you could use: `MediaElement.js`, but you'll need to integrate it into angular by yourself.